# How to Enable Logs for Hector Cassandra Client

Tags: logging, cassandra, hector

I am using Hector jar to communicate with Cassandra 1.x.x in production code. Off-late I am getting few problems where the call-stack is pointing to the Jar code. I am pretty sure that the problem is either with the Cassandra connection or the server on which the application is hosted. But somehow my application is  not able to log the logs printed inside hector jar.
Can you please provide me some clue how to get it logged, tried looking online but couldn't find anything.

The key problems which I am facing are

1. The thread is sleeping for 5 seconds during skipping the hosts.
2. The thread is getting blocked/taking lot of time while reading data from socket.

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You're probably having a hard time finding resources online, because Hector was deprecated and marked as "inactive" on GitHub 5 years ago: https://github.com/hector-client/hector

Comment: Yes i am aware of the fact that it has been inactive since long, we too have plan to upgrade the cassandra version and the driver. But as of now I have to deal with this.